# AngularJS: ng-repeat not displaying JSON

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm trying to get Angular to display JSON data that I've managed to pull from a database via PDO. The PDO part and JSON encode part is working fine -- console is returning the data as expected.

However, when using ng-repeat the `div`s do display but `post.time` does not show.

**HTML**

```
<html ng-app="dataVis">
    . . .
    <body ng-controller="GraphController as graph">
        <div ng-repeat="post in graph.posts track by $index">
            {{post.time}}
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**JSON data**

```
[
    {
        "time": "1340",
        "postId": "282301",
        "likes": "2"
    },
    {
        "time": "1300",
        "postId": "285643",
        "likes": "0"
    }
] . . . (etc)
```

**JS**

```
(function () {

  var app = angular.module('dataVis', []);

  app.controller('GraphController', ['$http', function ($http) {
    var graph = this;
    graph.posts = [];
    $http.get('/query-general.php').success(function (data) {
      console.log(data); // returns JSON data
      graph.posts = data;
    });

  }]);

}());
```

At first I did not include `track by $index` but upon receiving a dupes error I decided to include it.

I would like to display the JSON data in the HTML page using ng-repeat. Can anybody lend a helping hand to get this working?

Comment: Put everything here please.

Comment: Have you verified the data is successfully returned from the HTTP request?

Comment: Yes, the data is successfully returned. `console.log(data)` returns the expected JSON data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the issue. I had comments in my php files outside of the php tags. So when angular tries to get the JSON data from the php page, the comments were fetched too. Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare $scope.graph variable at first, before you can pass data to $scope.graph.posts.

```
$scope.graph = {};
$scope.graph.posts = data;
```

Working example - JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/RkykR/294/

HTML

```
<h3>Ng-Repeat example</h3>
<div ng-app ng-controller="MyCtrl">

<table>
    <thead>
        <tr><td>time</td>
            <td>postID</td>
    <td>likes</td>
        </tr>
        </thead>
    <tbody>
                <tr ng-repeat="item in graph.posts"><td>{{item.time}}</td>
            <td>{{item.postId}}</td>
    <td>{{item.likes}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

JavaScript

```
   var data = [
    {
        "time": "1340",
        "postId": "282301",
        "likes": "2"
    },
    {
        "time": "1300",
        "postId": "285643",
        "likes": "0"
    }
];

function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.graph = {};
    $scope.graph.posts = data;
}
```

CSS

```
table {
    padding:5px;
    width:500px;

}

table td {
    border: 1px solid gray;
    padding:3px 0;
    text-align:center;
}

table thead td {
    font-weight:bold;
}
```

Comment: not true, this question uses the "controller as" syntax and does not require the injection of $scope nor the registration of `graph` on the `$scope`. graph === $scope.

Answer (score 0):

Because json is naming the properties as `"time"` rather than `time`, have you tried using array notation to access them?
e.g

```
<td>{{item["time"]}}</td>
<td>{{item["postId"]}}</td>
<td>{{item["likes"]}}</td>
```