# ng-repeat gets commented and doesn´t show results from a JSON object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have this code, and I don´t know why, but ng-repeat Directive gets commented and doesn´t show the results of the JSON object. I have checked if the object is properly passed to "this.paises2 with the toSource() method and it seems everything is fine.

I have checked here, but nothing works:

[AngularJS: ng-repeat not displaying JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27142413/angularjs-ng-repeat-not-displaying-json)

[ng-repeat code getting commented out when viewed from browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31426872/ng-repeat-code-getting-commented-out-when-viewed-from-browser)

[ngRepeat div get commented out when i see from the browser inspector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43739301/ngrepeat-div-get-commented-out-when-i-see-from-the-browser-inspector)

Here is the  HTML code:

```
<html ng-app="miModulo">



<head>

    <link href="mis-css.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

</head>

<body ng-controller="miControlador as vm">

    <button ng-click="vm.buscarEnRegion()">Pulsar</button>



    <ul ng-repeat="elemento in vm.paises">
    <li>

        {{elemento.name}}



    </li>

    </ul>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>

    <script src="mijs1.js"></script>

</body>
```

And the Javascript/ Angular JS code:

```
angular
.module("miModulo",[])
.controller("miControlador",['$http',funcionPrincipal] ); 

function funcionPrincipal($http)
{   
    this.buscarEnRegion=function()
    {
        $http.get("https://restcountries.eu/rest/v1/region/africa").then(function(miRespuesta) 
        {
            this.paises=miRespuesta;

        //  alert(miRespuesta.toSource());

        alert(this.paises.toSource());



        },function(miRespuesta)
        {

            alert("incorrecto");
        }



        ); //then


    }


}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you create a JSFiddle?

Comment: change ng-repeat from ul to li

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple issues. From the [angular docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#general-usage)

> The response object has these properties:
>
> - data – {string|Object} – The response body transformed with the
> - transform functions. status – {number} – HTTP status code of the
> - response. headers – {function([headerName])} – Header getter function.
> - config – {Object} – The configuration object that was used to generate
> - the request. statusText – {string} – HTTP status text of the response.
> - xhrStatus – {string} – Status of the XMLHttpRequest (complete, error, timeout or abort).

So what you want is `miRespuesta.data`.

The other issue is when you do `this.paises=miRespuesta`, `this` refers to the the function, not the controller. So you need to assign a variable to the controller. So change your controller to this:

```
function funcionPrincipal($http)
{   
    var vm = this;
    vm.buscarEnRegion=function()
    {
        $http.get("https://restcountries.eu/rest/v1/region/africa").then(function(miRespuesta) 
        {
            vm.paises=miRespuesta.data;
        },function(miRespuesta)
        {
            alert("incorrecto");
        }
        ); //then
    }
}
```

See [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/9fX9gJPWsvQMeHRk9VvC?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works perfectly! I must understand the "this" problem, cause I am not able to see it in my head properly. I thought the JSON object was a string, because I misunderstood when I read that JSON objects are text, and I thought that meant string.

Answer (score 0):

Change this

```
<ul ng-repeat="elemento in vm.paises">
    <li>
    {{elemento.name}}
    </li>
</ul>
```

to this

```
<ul >
    <li ng-repeat="elemento in vm.paises">
    {{elemento.name}}
   </li>
</ul>
```